# org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: missing ) after argument list error when updating session storage key value using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, session-storage

If key value length is 11808 Unable to update session storage key value using selenium automation 
Small length key values are setting but long length key values getting JS error

Manually it is working but using selenium automation getting JS error.
setItemInsessionStorage method using:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: missing ) after argument list
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
java.lang.AssertionError: org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: missing ) after argument list
```

...implies that there is a syntax error within the *Javascript* line of code.

A bit of more information about your usecase interms of your code block would have helped us to analyze the error in a better way. However in majority of the cases, this error is observed in the following cases:

- Incase the `"` marks are not escaped properly. As an example:

  ```
  onclick="(canLaunch('" + v.LibraryItemId + " '))"
          ^ escape character is missing
  ```

  Ideally, the line should be:

  ```
  onclick=\"(canLaunch('" + v.LibraryItemId + " '))\"
  ```
- Incase the `function()` passed are not closed properly. As an example:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){

  }
  ```

  Ideally, the line should be:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){

  });
  ```

Comment: No issue with " or closing brackets